# Import CSV or XML to MySQL

Tags: mysql, xml, database, csv

I have two huge databases in both formats CSV & XML, and I want to import to MySQL the databases.

I tried to used : LOAD DATA INFILE, but I receive this error message :
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

MySQL Version : 5.1.56-log

I tried without any success to use PHP to convert XML to array then Insert line by line.

EDIT :

I used this query as root to import XML to MySQL :

LOAD XML LOCAL FILE '/home/floupie/public_html/All.xml' INTO TABLE `k_logs`;

Comment: what's the SQL you used for LOAD DATA INFILE?

Comment: LOAD XML LOCAL FILE '/home/floupie/public_html/All.xml' INTO TABLE `k_logs`;

Comment: you mean `LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE`?

Comment: yes, I just used Dennis syntax but no result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the appropriate syntax for a csv load.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/importfile.csv' 
INTO TABLE test_table 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
(field1, filed2, field3);
```

This is the appropriate syntax for an xml load.

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'items.xml'
INTO TABLE item
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<item>';
```

Comment: The same error :

using :
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE '/home/hotels/public_html/Hotels_All.xml'

INTO TABLE hotels

ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<hotel>';

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'XML LOCAL INFILE '/home/hotels/public_html/Hotels_All.xml'
INTO TABLE hotels
ROW' at line 1

Comment: LOAD XML INFILE is available from MySQL 5.2 and higher, what version are you using?

Comment: Try a new version of MySQL if possible, otherwise I recommend the following link http://ftp.nchu.edu.tw/MySQL/tech-resources/articles/xml-in-mysql5.1-6.0.html .