# php importing csv into database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a csv file with 65000 records which i need to import into my database.

I have tried following code but real slow.

Is they anyway I can do this faster.

```
@set_time_limit(1200);
    $file = './csvFiles/aw_Products.csv';
    $handle = fopen( $file , 'r');
    while (($row = fgetcsv($handle)) !== false) {       
        if( is_integer($row[0]) || $row[0] != 0 )
        {
            $product = new Product();
            $product->merchant_id       = $row[0];
            $product->merc_product_id   = $row[1];
            $product->product_id        = $row[2];
            $product->product_name      = $row[3];
            $product->product_desc      = htmlentities($row[4]);
            //$product->keywords            = htmlentities($row[6]);
            $product->category_id       = $row[5];
            $product->link_url          = $row[6];
            $product->image_url         = $row[7];
            $product->price             = $row[8];
            $product->delivery_cost     = $row[9];
            //$product->deliveryAvailable   = $row[12];
            //$product->deliveryDetails = $row[13];
            //$product->valid_to            = $row[14];
            //$product->valid_from      = ($row[3] == 'yes') ? 1 : 0;

            if( Product::find_by_id( $row[0] ) )
                $product->updateRecord();
            else
                $product->createRecord();
        }
        sleep (1);
    }
    fclose($handle);
```

Comment: Maybe this is more appropriate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057377/import-csv-or-xml-to-mysql

Comment: What is `sleep (1);` for? You're calling it 65000 times, so of course it might take a while.

Comment: Try to place this code -> $product = new Product() outside the loop..

Comment: sleep(1) * 65000 = 65000 secs ~ 1083 mins ~ 18 hours. Remove the `sleep` and your insert should speed up significantly.

Comment: @Wesley Murch just to sllep for  second

Comment: If you're going to sleep for a second, things are going to be slow. You're asking it to be slow, so it's going to be slow.

Comment: beside the "sleep", you re-instantiate the same class in every loop (65000 times), it might decrease the script performance. How about instantiating the class before the while loop.

Comment: @Levi Morrison i tried your link it took 5 second to import this data. thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

`sleep()` is probably the culprit.  But I am also wondering about this: `Product::find_by_id()` because it might be doing a SELECT query for every INSERT.  You might think about making a single SELECT query to get all of the existing DB keys into a PHP array, then you can use *in_array()* to check whether to UPDATE or INSERT.  Probably goes without saying, but you will want to add to the PHP array if you INSERT.

Answer (score 1):

Give up sleep() and use prepared statements for mysql insert/updates.